# Replicate Firestore workflow in AWS

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-firestore

I did a quick proof of concept for a simple Firestore backed Angular app.  However, my company is in the AWS ecosystem.  Is there a similar rx workflow to the below if we're simply storing collections of json objects in AWS?

Here's the basics of what I had to do in Firestore:

```
  public get mentors(): Observable<Participant[]> {
    return this._mentors.valueChanges();
  }

  public get mentorEntries(): Observable<DocumentChangeAction<Participant>[]> {
    return this._mentors.snapshotChanges();
  }
  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore) {

      this._mentors = this.firestore.collection('mentors');
  }

  public addMentor(mentor: Participant): Promise<DocumentReference> {
    return this._mentors.add(mentor);
  }
```

```
  mentors$: Observable<Participant[]>;

  constructor(private participantService: ParticipantService) {
    this.mentors$ = participantService.mentors;
  }
```

```
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.existingDocument) {
      this.existingDocument.payload.doc.ref.update(this.registerForm.value)
        .then(this.handleFulfilled, this.handleRejected);
    } else {
      this.participantService.addMentor(this.registerForm.value)
        .then(this.handleFulfilled, this.handleRejected);
    }
  }
```

For my needs, the simplicity of Firestore rx was perfect.  Reading the Amplify docs, I see a lot of promises, would I need to track changes by hand?  Does AWS have a similar rx construct?